# Haversine formula in Java producing incorrect result

Tags: java, math, gps, formula, haversine

I am trying to use this implementation of `Haversine formula` [given on wikipedia](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#Java) for trial but this formula is not giving expected result.

```
public class Haversine {
    public static final double R = 6372.8; // In kilometers
    public static double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        return R * c;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(haversine(36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40));
    }
}
```

---

```
Input GPS latitude format  : ddmm.mmmm
Input GPS longitude format : dddmm.mmmm
```

Above formats for lat-lon are specified in requirement document.

Sample input coordinates are as below :

```
lat1 = 3359.64868, lon1 = 8356.178
lat2 = 3359.649,   lon2 = 8356.178
```

Before passing these values to Haversine method, I am converting these values into degrees format. **Please correct me if this step is not necessary.**

I am using formula below to convert from degree minute format to Decimal degree format :

```
Decimal Degree = degree + (minute / 60)
```

So new coordinates become

```
lat1 = 33 + (59.64868 / 60) = 33.994144666666664
lon1 = 83 + (56.178 / 60) = 83.9363

lat2 = 33 + (59.649 / 60) = 33.99415
lon2 = 83 + (56.178 / 60) = 83.9363
```

Call to haversine method becomes like

```
haversine(33.994144666666664, 83.9363, 33.99415, 83.9363)
```

which is returning value `5.932071604620887E-4`

To validate the values, I provided same input `(33.994144666666664, 83.9363, 33.99415, 83.9363)` to converter present on [this website](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/) but it gives result as `0.001` km.

I tried to provide input values without converting to decimal degrees but then also output from two methods is not matching.

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Please comment for downvote

Comment: Have you tried walking through your program with a calculator and seeing where the results diverge?

Comment: Yes and no. I have calculated degree/minute conversion with calculator but I have not debugged java code given on wiki because I was expecting that this code is correct.

Comment: Well, why not give it a try?

Answer (score 5):

The result `5.932071604620887E-4` you are getting is the representation of `5.932071604620887 * 10^(-4)`, which is `5.932071604620887 / 10000 = 0.0005932071604620887`.

If the website returns `0.001`, my suggestions is they just round to the 3rd decimal place. Hence, your calculation is correct.