# Calculate distance between points in Array and return array with points that are less than 5km between them

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array with latitude and longitude [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4),(x5,y5)...] where x is latitude and y is longitude I want to return an array with the distance between them is less than 5KM. for example, the returned array would be (x2,y2),(x3,y3) which means the distance between this points is less than 5km.i am using the Haversine algorithm to calculate the distance between two points.
Haversine.distance(x1,y1,x2,y2).how do i achive this in java?

this is what i tried,

```
 public static class  Point{
        private final double latitude;
        private final double longitude;
    }



Point p1 = new Point(53.594952,-1.291583);
        Point p2 = new Point(53.383100,-1.179820);
        Point p3 = new Point(53.594952,-1.179120);
        Point p4 = new Point(53.594952,-1.279120);
        Point p5 = new Point(53.594952,-1.479120);
        Point p6 = new Point(53.594952,-1.339120);

Point[] points = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6};
        Point[] nearPoints = new Point[points.length];

for (int i = 0; i <= points.length - 1; i++) {
    if (Haversine.distance(points[i].latitude, points[i].longitude, points[i + 1].latitude, points[i + 1].longitude) < 5) {
        nearPoints[i] = points[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Can you show us any Java code?

Comment: If you have 3 points where A and B are 5km less and B and C are 5km are less, but A to C are 10km what the result array will contains?

Comment: Also, your current code assume that the array of parameter is ordered, so if A to C are 5km it will not get it... I think you best result is permute every position with everyother and get the result as a List<Pair<Point, Point>>

Comment: it will contain A,B,C since A,B,and C

Comment: check this post for the javacode [haversine-formula-in-java-producing-incorrect-result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776344/haversine-formula-in-java-producing-incorrect-result)

Comment: @Gambotic That doesn't have anything to do with the question, OP is looking for how to compare his already-calculated distances and store the results

Comment: @Epicular The question is "Haversine.distance(x1,y1,x2,y2).how do i achive this in java? " -> Answer is to me, how to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the end result is a data structure containing all sets of points

```
Point[] p = [new Point(x1,y1), new Point(x2,y2),...];
List<Point[]> closePoints = new ArrayList<Point[]>();

for (int i=0; i<p.length-1; i++) {
  for (int j=i+1; j<p.length; j++) {
    if (Haversine.distance(p[i].latitude, p[i].longitude, p[j].latitude, p[j].longitude) < 5) {
      //Elements are inserted into the list as two-element arrays
      Point[] toAdd = {p[i], p[j]};
      closePoints.add(toAdd);
    }
  }
}
System.out.println(closePoints.get(0)[0].latitude); //access example
```

edit: made the data structure contain pairs of points within two-element arrays instead of storing one point after another